# React Native Fade Right/Left View on Scroll Down

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have 3 `View` in a `ScrollView` and How Can I Fade Right or Left each `View` on Scroll Down ?

```
<ScrollView >
  <View>
    <Text>Fade Right View 1</Text>
  </View>

  <View>
    <Text>Fade Right View 2</Text>
  </View>

  <View>
    <Text>Fade Right View 3</Text>
  </View>
</ScrollView >
```

Something like this:
Element Fade In on Scroll (https://codepen.io/annalarson/pen/GesqK)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have created a small example for you, but of course you need to fine tune it to be fully functional for your purposes.

**Demo**

[image: gif]

**Explanation**

My example consists of two components. A Fade component and the actual ScrollView. The Fade Component handles the animation. The fade in animation is triggered by scrolling through the ScrollView (see handleScroll function).

**Fade Component**

```
class Fade extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: props.visible,
      visibility: new Animated.Value(props.visible ? 1 : 0),
    };
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.visible) {
      this.setState({ visible: true });
    }
    Animated.timing(this.state.visibility, {
      toValue: nextProps.visible ? 1 : 0,
      duration: 500,
    }).start(() => {
      this.setState({ visible: nextProps.visible });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { style} = this.props;

    const containerStyle = {
      opacity: this.state.visibility.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0, 1],
      }), // interpolate opacity 
      transform: [
        {
            translateX: this.state.visibility.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 1],
                outputRange: [-20, 0],
            }), // interpolate translateX to create a fade in left/right
        },
      ],
    };

    const combinedStyle = [containerStyle, style];
    return (
      <Animated.View style={this.state.visible ? combinedStyle : containerStyle} />
    );
  }
}
```

**ScrollView Snippet**

```
handleScroll(e) {
    if (e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y > 50) { // you need to fine tune this value
      this.setState({ visible: true }); 
    }
  }


<ScrollView onScroll={(e) => this.handleScroll(e) } scrollEventThrottle={8}>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', height: 200, marginTop: 10 }}/>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', height: 200, marginTop: 10 }}/>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', height: 200, marginTop: 10 }}/>
          <Fade style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 200, marginTop: 10 }} visible={this.state.visible} />
</ScrollView>
```

I hope my example gives you an idea how you can achieve your intended behavior.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `onScroll` like this :

```
<ScrollView onScroll={this.handleScroll} />
```

After that :

```
handleScroll = (event: Object) => {
 console.log(event.nativeEvent);
 // You see {layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize} in nativeEvent
}
```

With `contentOffset`, `layoutMeasurement` and `contentSize` you can rewrite [Element Fade In on Scroll](https://codepen.io/annalarson/pen/GesqK) in React Native!

Comment: Could you please explain more details about Conditions to achieve that?